# Displaying image returned with REST call

Tags: image, rest, angular, response, render

I want to display the image of an item the user picks. When the user clicks on an item a rest call is made and an image is retrieved but I cannot display it.

I have tried following the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080654/ionic-2-angular-2-images-prepended-with-unsafe-therefore-not-displaying-ev) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324762/angular-2-render-byte-from-web-api-as-an-image-src) but cannot seem to get them to work.

The basic principle (to my understanding) is that when the rest call response with (what is supposed to be) an image/png type I can format my image source in my TS like this:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(private _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer ){}
```

...

```
this.showPage = "data:image/png;base64," + rest_response;
```

then use "DomSanitizer" to enable this to be used in the html like this:

```
<img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(showPage )">
```

but when I try to use it the image is broken and when I inspect it I see:

```
src="data:image/png;base64,�PNG...,㘑��" etc...
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: is your rest backend encoding the image to base64 before returning it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.showPage = "data:image/png;base64," + rest_response;
```

and then simply,

```
<img [src]="showPage" />
```

As answered in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913967/displaying-an-embedded-image-in-angular2).

Comment: The image is still broken but now the source data starts with "unsafe:"

Comment: I've seen others use DomSanitizationService instead of DomSanitizer and then also importing BROWSER_SANITIZATION_PROVIDERS and listing it as a provider. [More here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324762/angular-2-render-byte-from-web-api-as-an-image-src)