# How to pass a response from service to component?

Tags: angular, lumen

I am trying to pass a response from my service to component so I can display it on the html page but I cant figure out how.

The component

```
uploadFile(): void {

  this.errors = null;

  let file = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
  if (file.files && file.files[0]) {
    let fileToUpload = file.files[0];
    this.getInfoService
      .uploadImage(fileToUpload)
      .subscribe(
        response => { console.log(response) },
        err => {
          //this.errors = err._body
          this.errors = err.json().image
          console.log("ERR", err.json().image)
        },
        () => console.log("()",'worked')
      );
  }
```

}

EDIT: Problem was in my service. Here is the working code.

```
uploadImage(fileToUpload: any) : Observable<any> {

  let input = new FormData();
  input.append("image", fileToUpload);
  return this.http.post('http://Api.app/api/v1/upload', input)
    .map(
      (response: Response) =>  {
        // I was missing this part
        response.json()
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck? You can see the things you need in the object, do you really not know how you get at them?

Comment: No obviously I dont man thats why I'm asking. I'm stuck at the part about how to pass the things in the object to the component so I can display them on my html page

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a couple of properties on your component and the assign the response data to those properties.

```
image: any;
message: string;

uploadFile(): void {

  this.errors = null;

  let file = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
  if (file.files && file.files[0]) {
    let fileToUpload = file.files[0];
    this.getInfoService
      .uploadImage(fileToUpload)
      .subscribe(
        response => { 
            this.image = response.image;
            this.message = response.message;
       },
        err => {
          //this.errors = err._body
          this.errors = err.json().image
          console.log("ERR", err.json().image)
        },
        () => console.log("()",'worked')
      );
  }
}
```

To display your message in your view:

```
{{ message }}
```

To display the embedded image, you will need to look at this post:

[Angular2 Displaying an embedded image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914001/5660649)

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. I was logging the response in the service but I wasnt assigning it! I'll update the OP.